# ASP.net como faco para mandar texto com enter

Tags: asp.net, webforms

no Exemplo.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      teste0989.InnerText="teste123<br>teste456<br>"
    }
```

no site aparece o br como texto e na verdade queria que desse enter alguma sugestão

Answer (score 4):

Creio que o que você procura é isso:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   teste0989.InnerHtml="teste123<br>teste456<br>"
}
```

o `InnerText` já escapa os caracteres especiais para que sejam exibidos como texto. A solução é trocar por `InnerHtml`.

Comment: funcionou muito bem obrigado